# Short Story Collection from 80s/early 90s with story about the Ainu and a shapeshifter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, shape-shifter

I'm looking for the short story collection that contained a short story that involved the Ainu culture and shape shifters.

I read the collection in late 80s/early 90s. It was published in America — so in English. I can't remember the theme of the collection but it could have been "Winter" — so fantasy stories with a Winter theme. I believe the Ainu one was in a Winter setting.

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to need more information. When did you read this? In what country? Was it in English? Were all of the stories about the Ainu or about shapeshifters? Did just one tick both boxes? Or were they two different stories? If it is both, it's likely referring to the *mujina*, but I'd need more information to narrow it down.

Comment: I read the collection in late 80s/early 90s. It was an published in America - so in English. That particular story was about Ainu and a shapeshifter. I can't remember the theme of the collection but it could have been "Winter" - so fantasy stories with a Winter theme.  I believe the Ainu one was in a Winter setting.